# Use value from php into jquery

Tags: php, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  "use strict";
  var id_var = "<?php echo $id_question; ?>";

  $("#option1").click(function() {
    alert(id_var);
    $.post('updateDatabase.php', {
      id: id_var,
      option: "option1_clicked"
    });
  });

<?php 

$id = $_POST['id'];
$option = $_POST['option'];
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "" , "log_database");

if ($option == 'option1_clicked') {
    $queryOption1 = "UPDATE `questions` SET `option1_clicked` = `option1_clicked` + 1 WHERE id='$id'";
    $query_run_option1 = mysqli_query($connection,$queryOption1);
}
?>
```

When I enter in the id field of my `$.post` an id from my database it updates correctly.
When I do an `alert(id_var)` to check if the variable gets the correct value, it works.

So you would think (at least I do) when I put `id_var` after `id:` it will update my database but this doesn't work.

Why?

Comment: You're showing the wrong code as the problem lies on the server side.

Comment: `"So you would think [...] it will update my database"` - I wouldn't think that at all from the code shown.  Because there's nothing here that updates a database.  You may be under the common yet mistaken impression that the rest of your code must be without flaw and that JavaScript and/or PHP itself must be broken in some way.  This assumption should be put aside for debugging purposes.

Comment: You have confirmed that there's nothing wrong with the php to jquery code, now you need to look at your jquery to php code, ie "updateDatebase.php" (which you've not included as already observed).  eg what's the method php's signature?  Maybe it's not expecting "?id=" but instead is expected "?id_question=" as in the earlier code.

Comment: can you please on your updateDatabase.php put a line print_r($_POST) and check what value is sending id_var on that case?

Comment: may be you are specting id_var been a number and it is decoding as string try parseInt(id_var) if thats the case

Comment: @NoelCarcases, I entered my php code

Comment: @David, I entered my php code

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: Dump the `$_POST` array to make sure that it contains what you expect. You should also check the error log if there's any errors and check the network tab in your browsers developer console to see if the request gets called correctly. Basically, you should do some basic debugging to find out where your code fails.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I'm just learning php and stuff so its all new to me. On the console it says ReferenceError: var_id is not defined.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson it found the problem, I just had to do a parseInt(id_var). Thanks for the answers